# blank white space due to position constraint?

Tags: html, css, header, position, whitespace

I am building a website and I am still in the stages of learning, I'd say this is my most complex layout. Basically I have an unusual banner at the top of my page which I think is causing my problem. Above the footer of my page there is a large white space. I think it is caused by the face I have had to use things like top:-200px; on some of my divs so that they are in the right place.

It would really help to have someone with more experienced eyes to look it over.

Here is the website -
www.redchevron.co.uk

and here is the html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footer.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home_stylesheet.css">
<title>Red Chevron | Graphic Design</title>
<META NAME="description" CONTENT="At Red Chevron, we strive to bring you crisp, quality designs to suit your needs.  Digital Graphics | Corporate Identity | Promotional Material">
<META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="graphics, rob, jeffrey, graphic, design, photoshop, logo, business, card, leaflet, flyer, freelance, red, chevron, redchevron, designer, digital, quality, media">
<script>
  $(“body”).Scrollbar();
  </script>
</head>

<body>



<div class="banner">
<div class="navigation">

        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav"></a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="#">Contact</a></li>


        </ul>

      </div>
</div>

<div class="headround">

</div>

<div class="headlogo">
<img src="images/head_logo.png">
</div>

<!-- stop here for header -->


<div class="maincont">
<div class="mainfeat">
<img src="images/feat_flag.png">
<div class="maininfo"><!--feature-->

</div>
</div>
  </div>


<div class="maincont">
<div class="mainfeat">
<img src="images/news_flag.png">
<div class="maininfo"><!--news-->
  <h2> Coming Soon </h2>
Thank you for visiting Red Chevron.<br><br>
My name is Rob Jeffrey, founder of Red Chevron. I offer quality, affordable graphic design services to suit your needs. 
Whether you need a new Corporate Identity, promotional material, or anything in between, I am here to make your ideas a reality.<br><br>

I have spent over 6 years refining and polishing my Digital Design skills in order to give my clients the very best results.<br><br>
Unfortunately this site is currently under construction.<br>
If you would like to contact me, please use the details below:<br><br>
Rob Jeffrey<br>
<b>Call:</b> 07925 870385<br>
  <b>Email:</b> rob.jeffrey@redchevron.co.uk 
</div>
</div>
  </div>


<div class="maincont">
<div class="mainfeat">
<img src="images/pipe_flag.png">
<div class="maininfo"><!--pipeline-->

</div>
</div>

    <div class="footer">
&copy; 2014 Red Chevron  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; All Rights Reserved
  </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Start of footer -->




</body>

</html>
```

And the css -

Header -

```
*{
margin:0px;
  padding:0px;

}

body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}


.banner{
width:100%;
height:80px;
position:relative;
z-index:10;
background-color:white;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  overflow:hidden;

}

.headround{
background: #fff;
  position:relative;
  float: center;
    margin:auto;
  height: 76px;
  width: 164px;
  z-index:100;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 76px 76px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 76px 76px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 76px 76px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.headlogo{
position:relative;
z-index:101;
width:124px;
margin:auto;
float:center;
top:-144px;
}

.navigation
{
  width: 1300px;
  overflow:auto;
  margin:25px auto 0px auto;
  padding:0px;
  float:center;



}


ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0;
text-align:center;

}


li {
  display:inline-block;
  float:center;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:34px;
font-family:walkway;
}

.nav {
  display:inline-block;
  width:250px;
  height:30px;
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
  padding:2px;
  float:center;


}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background-color: rgba(235,235,235,1);
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;

}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
 background-color: rgba(231,52,39,1);
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover,
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal:hover {
 background: rgba(231,52,39,1);

}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
 background-color: rgba(231,52,39,1);
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
 }
```

Home page style sheet -

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

body{
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.maincont{
  margin:0 auto;
  float:center;
  width:1350px;
  padding-left:1px;
  height:auto;
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
  top:-220px;
  color:white;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:11pt;
}

.mainfeat{
  width:450px;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
  margin:auto;

}



.maininfo{
  height:428px;
  width:378px;
  top:-56px;
  z-index:-1;
  position:relative;
  background:#303030;
  margin:0px 30px;
  padding:61px 5px 5px 5px;
}

h2{
  color:#e73427;
}
```

and Footer -

```
.footer{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center;
  color:#b4b4b4;
  font-family:verdana;
  clear:both;
  padding:10px;
  bottom:-100px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Like I said I'm a beginner so if there is a much more logical way of constructing my banner and getting rid of the white space, please let me know.

Many thanks guys

Comment: What footer? I see no footer in Chrome

Comment: @mplungjan: zoom out, and you'll see it. It's a small copyright message

Comment: thats another odd thing, ive hidden all the scrollbars but using a mouse wheel, it scrolls down, or by clicking the text, holding, and dragging down, the page scrolls. It should just be dark text, the basic copyright stuff.

Comment: It scrolls nowhere - under no circumstance can I get to the footer in Chrome on OSX

Comment: Ditto - page doesn't scroll at all. @rjcreatives You might find it easier to use a grid system like 960.gs (http://960.gs/).

Comment: @RJcreatives: You have an overflow-y:hidden in your CSS, which is stopping us from scrolling down. Removing it allows us to see the entire page. It doesn't solve your original problem though.

Comment: huh,odd. i promise I'm scrolling right now in chrome even after clearing my cache. no idea how thats happening. I have build a couple sites with the 960 gs but for my own i fancied something different.

Comment: ive disabled the hidden overflow so shortly the scrollbar should appear

Comment: Replace `$(“body”).Scrollbar();` with `$("body").Scrollbar();`

Comment: Well spotted, but did not fix anything - since there is no jQuery loaded there is no point anyway and it likely should have been `<script>$(function() $("body").Scrollbar();})</script>
`

Comment: @stealthyninja Ive replaced that line like you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the culprit is, as you say, your usage of position CSS. If I disable `top: -220px;` from your maincont divs, the gap is eliminated.

As for a solution...? I'm not too sure, really. There are plenty of neater ways to code what you're trying to do, using different methods, from what I'm seeing in your page source.

Perhaps someone else might be able to suggest ways you can fix it up, but from my perspective, I would redo more or less everything, because of other issues, such as the one we discussed in the comments regarding overflow-y. Plus, the width of the page and your overflow-x would essentially stop users on smaller screens/browser widths/resolutions from seeing a good chunk of the right side of your site.

Comment: Unfortunately 90% of what I know is self taught so its down to a terrible case of amateur problem solving. But some advice on how to better code my header and overlay my flag.pngs with by content boxes, would be good. good point about the scrollbars thought, ill sort that now, Thanks

Comment: No worries. I know that feeling all too well. Some suggestions would be to put your logo in the same divs as your navbar. Here you can use your positioning CSS to get it in the vertical center. That way, your logo will move with the rest of your page when someone zooms, or on smaller setups. You can also do navigation>ul{font-size:0;} to remove the gaps between your navbar links (you can see the gaps if you press ctrl+a on your page). I'd give more advice, but comment boxes are sort of restrictive!

Answer (score 0):

Not the best nor neatest way to code, but sometimes a negative margin on the bottom the equivalent of the negative top works or change the top:-220px; to margin-top:-220px;

Comment: ooo seems to be acting differently now, just gona have to tweak but for some reason when i edit a css my server takes a few minutes to update the page. Ill mark this as an answer if it works